# Create XML with variabile rows

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am creating XML VB.Net and have a problem with adding rows.

The XML should have a different number of rows (some 5, some 100,...) and also with different values in the attributes.

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim xmlDeclaration As New XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes")
    Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://www.dmysite.com"
    Dim dt As Date = Date.Today
    Dim te As Integer = Int((100 * Rnd()) + 150)

    Dim doc As XDocument =
    New XDocument(xmlDeclaration,
        New XElement(ns + "Entry",
            New XElement(ns + "StandardHeader",
                New XAttribute("Id", "BRaB")),
        New XElement(ns + "List",
        New XElement(ns + "List1",
            New XAttribute("Type", dt),
            New XAttribute("aId", te)))))

    doc.Save("C:\temp\testni.xml")

End Sub
```

With the current code the XML looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entry xmlns="http://www.dmysite.com">
  <StandardHeader Id="BRaB" />
  <List>
    <List1 Type="2019-05-24T00:00:00+02:00" aId="203" />
  </List>
</Entry>
```

I would like to have the XML like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entry xmlns="http://www.dmysite.com">
  <StandardHeader Id="BRaB" />
  <List>
    <List1 Type="2019-05-24T00:00:00+02:00" aId="203" />
    <List1 ..... />
    <List1 ..... />
    <List1 ..... />
    <List1 ..... />
    <List1 ..... />
    .
    .
    .
  </List>
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a solution like the following to create the XML document:

```vb
'create a new xml document
Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument()

'create the xml declaration and append to the xml document
Dim docXmlDeclaration As Xml.XmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes")
doc.AppendChild(docXmlDeclaration)

'set the xml namespace.
Dim ns As String = "http://www.dmysite.com"

'create the "Entry" element (this is the root element of your xml document).
Dim nodeEntry As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Entry", ns)

'create the "StandardHeader" element.
Dim nodeEntryStandardHeader As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("StandardHeader", ns)

'create the "Id" attribute of the "StandardHeader" element.
Dim attrId As Xml.XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Id")
attrId.Value = "BRaB"
nodeEntryStandardHeader.Attributes.Append(attrId)

'now the "StandardHeader" element is created. Add this to the "Entry" element.
nodeEntry.AppendChild(nodeEntryStandardHeader)

'create the "List" element. This is the element to group the "List1" elements.
Dim nodeEntryList As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("List", ns)

'a loop to create multiple "List1" elements. You can change the 20 to another value.
For i As Integer = 0 To 20

    'create the "List1" element.
    Dim nodeEntryListList1 As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("List1", ns)

    'create the attributes "Type" and "aId" for the "List1" element.
    Dim attrType As Xml.XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Type")
    attrType.Value = Date.Today
    nodeEntryListList1.Attributes.Append(attrType)

    Dim attrAID As Xml.XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("aId")
    attrAID.Value = Int((100 * Rnd()) + 150)
    nodeEntryListList1.Attributes.Append(attrAID)

    'now the "List1" element is created. Add this to the "List" element.
    nodeEntryList.AppendChild(nodeEntryListList1)
Next

'the "List" element (with all child elements) is created. Add the "List" element to the "Entry" element.
nodeEntry.AppendChild(nodeEntryList)

'at the end add the "Entry" (root element) to the xml document (after the xml declaration).
doc.AppendChild(nodeEntry)

'now you can save the created xml document.
doc.Save("C:\temp\testni.xml")
```

Comment: Great. Just one additional question. Is any easy way to remove xmlns="" from nodes StandardHeader and List

Comment: @TomazP - updated the answer. Added the namespace to all the child nodes removes the empty `xmlns` attributes.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Ju save me a lot of time. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer using XDocument, but you can also use xml serialization. This allows you to keep your xml file structure in .Net classes, instead of building it manually. Reading and writing is simple with this approach.

Here are the vb.net classes which represent your data

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot("Entry", Namespace:="http://www.dmysite.com")>
Public Class Entry
    Public Property StandardHeader As StandardHeader
    Public Property List As New List()
End Class
Public Class StandardHeader
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Id As String
End Class
Public Class List
    <XmlElement("List1")>
    Public Property List1s As New List(Of List1)()
End Class
Public Class List1
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property [Type] As Date
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property aId As Integer
End Class
```

and the code to create the xml file, and then to read from it

```vb
Dim xmlPath = "C:\temp\testni.xml"
Dim r As New Random()
Dim myEntry As New Entry With {.StandardHeader = New StandardHeader() With {.Id = "BRaB"}}
Dim myList = New List()
For i = 1 To 5
    Dim te = r.Next(150, 251)
    myList.List1s.Add(New List1() With {.Type = Date.Now.Date, .aId = te})
Next
myEntry.List = myList
Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Entry))
Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(xmlPath)
    s.Serialize(sw, myEntry)
End Using
Dim myNewEntry As Entry
Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(xmlPath)
    myNewEntry = CType(s.Deserialize(sr), Entry)
End Using
```

if you need the Standalone attribute, change the serialization to this

```vb
Using ms = New StreamWriter(xmlPath)
    Using xr = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(ms, New Xml.XmlWriterSettings() With {.Encoding = Text.Encoding.UTF8})
        xr.WriteStartDocument(True)
        s.Serialize(xr, myEntry)
    End Using
End Using
```